# Sorting a checksums file by file name

Tags: unix, sorting, md5

I'm trying to sort the output of the `md5sum` program by file name, numerically (that is, file names all match `log-\d+\.txt`). I tried

```
sort -g "-t " -k 2 CHECKSUMS
```

but it sorts by checksum. Using

```
sort "-t " -k 2 CHECKSUMS
```

does sort by filename, but `log-12.txt` is placed before `log-2.txt`.

Any clues? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
$> sort -t '-' -k 2 -n CHECKSUMS
```

it splits the line `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  log-1.txt` at the `-` ... so the number is the firstmost string which allows `sort` to do the right thing(tm).

Comment: What if the number of dashes was not the same in every file (e.g. `a-1, a-2, a-a-1, b-1, b-a-a-1, b-a-b-1, b-a-b-2, ...`)? Is there a way to tell sort to start comparing numerically as soon as it finds a number in both strings being compared?

Comment: use other means (sed, awk, python, perl etc) to extract the number, put it infront of the filename and then use sort ...

Comment: Ok, did it with awk.